# Saving Find and Replace text function for .dat files in Powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

I'm making a script that will find and replace all the instances of a word with another. However I'm unsure how to save the changes.

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\Script.dat" -Raw
$old = 'oldword' 
$new = 'newword'
$file.Replace($old,$new)
```

Initially I had used the following but this caused issues.

```
$file.Replace($old,$new) | Set-Content $file
```

This caused the issue the error of

```
Set-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the same *some random stuff*...
```

How would I be able to save the changes and/or fix the above issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\Script.dat" -Raw
$old = 'oldword' 
$new = 'newword'
$file.Replace($old,$new) | Out-File -FilePath C:\Script.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close, but `Set-Content` needs two things: a path to the file location and the value to store. Personally, I prefer to overwrite variables when using the `.Replace()` method instead of piping it into other cmdlets.

This will do it:

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\Script.dat" -Raw
$old = 'oldword' 
$new = 'newword'
$file = $file.Replace($old,$new)
Set-Content -Path "C:\Script.dat" -Value $file
```

If possible, try to avoid storing files directly at `C:\` since that often needs admin rights to write to.

Additionally, you could pipe to `Set-Content` in a similar way originally listed but you still need to give it the path to the file:

```
$file.Replace($old,$new) | Set-Content "C:\Script.dat"
```